# What's a word for textbook-like writing?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that describes a detached style of writing, like a textbook or medical journal. I want one that's kind of like sterile but without the negative connotations. I feel like formal is too general, and academic doesn't fit the context well enough.

I think prosaic is pretty close to what I'm looking for, but I feel like it suggests that the writing is just ordinary and not detached/scientific.

Example:

He worried about the poetry exam because he was most familiar with  ______ writing.

Answer (score 5):

> I need a word that describes a detached style of writing, like a
> *textbook or medical journal*.

I believe that *academic writing* is, in fact, the label that suites your requirements by definition: it is the type of writing used in textbooks and journals. See the list of its characteristics below, which, in addition to *formal*, include *objective*, *balanced* and *evidenced*. These contribute to the "detached/scientific" quality you are looking for.

**academic** (writing)

> **What is academic writing?**
>
> **Academic writing** is writing which communicates ideas, information and
> research to the wider academic community. It can be divided into two
> types: **student academic writing,** which is used as a form of assessment
> at university, as well as at schools as preparation for university
> study; and **expert academic writing, which is writing that is
> intended for publication in an academic journal or book.**
>
> Both types of academic writing (student and expert) are expected to
> adhere to the same standards, which can be difficult for students to
> master. The characteristics of academic writing which together
> distinguish it from other forms of writing are that it is:
>
> structured;
> evidenced;
> critical;
> balanced;
> precise;
> objective;
> formal.
> ["Academic Writing", eapfoundation.com](https://www.eapfoundation.com/writing/what/)

> **What is academic writing?**
>
> **Academic writing is clear, concise, focussed, structured and backed up
> by evidence. Its purpose is to aid the reader’s understanding.**
>
> It has a formal tone and style, but it is not complex and does not
> require the use of long sentences and complicated vocabulary.
>
> Each subject discipline will have certain writing conventions,
> vocabulary and types of discourse that you will become familiar with
> over the course of your degree. However, there are some general
> characteristics of academic writing that are relevant across all
> disciplines. ["Academic Writing", library.leeds.ac.uk](https://library.leeds.ac.uk/info/14011/writing/106/academic_writing#:%7E:text=Academic%20writing%20is%20clear%2C%20concise,long%20sentences%20and%20complicated%20vocabulary.)

> **What is academic writing?**
>
> Loosely defined, **academic writing** is writing for academic
> purposes. That is, it is writing that explores or examines some aspect
> of knowledge. Generally, it is the kind of writing that scholars or
> academics produce (as philosophers, historians, social scientists,
> natural scientists, and so forth) **as can be seen in academic books
> and articles in academic journals**. There are of course, differences in
> such aspects as organization, vocabulary, and academic conventions
> from one discipline to another. [Pedro Pak-tao Ng; *Effective
> Writing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Effective_Writing/y7lQTr8bMq4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22what%20is%20academic%20writing%22%20textbooks%20journals&pg=PA11&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_writing) gives **scholarly writing** as a synonym.)

---

**academic** (adj.)

> Of, relating to, or characteristic of an educational institution or
> environment; concerned with the pursuit of research, education, and
> scholarship; scholarly, educational, intellectual. (OED)

Answer (score 2):

I would classify it as technical writing.

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_writing

Medical journals specifically utilize a lot of technical writing, so I believe this would be your best bet per your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**scholarly**

> Like a scholar, or learned person; showing the qualities of a scholar; as, a scholarly essay or critique.
> [Webster 1913](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/scholarly)

Answer (score 0):

**Empirical**. Not mere logic & theory. Based on experience, evidence, and calculations. It's precisely the language of textbooks. The language is disciplined language or regarding a level requiring students to demonstrate their understanding by communicating in an empirical way.

Comment: Hello, preWarp. This describes the content rather than the style used to communicate it. OP has considered 'prosaic', obviously referring to communication style rather than teaching method. The other answers overlap with teaching / teaching method, but are broad enough to include prevailing style.

Comment: That's incorrect. You are not speaking with proficiency. Could you please blow smoke some where else? And your own confusion doesn't dignify a explanation of my reply to the original poster.